# Run a command if stdin is empty

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I'd like to do the reverse of `xargs --no-run-if-empty`, so that it ONLY runs if the stdin is empty.

Example use:

```bsh
ip a | fgrep "inet " | grep -ve " tun" -e " lo"
# pipe it into something and echo localhost if empty
```

Comment: Should the solution consume the stream if not empty? Or pass it through?

Comment: This is perilously close to being an XY Problem. Please forget about the _how_ for a moment and explain _what_ you're trying to achieve with this pipeline.

Comment: `ip a | awk '/inet / && !/ tun| lo/'`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `grep` returns an error code when it finds nothing (has no output). Therefore we don't need to look at its stdout. We can instead look at the error code. `||` will do this and only run the following command, if the earlier command fails.

`ip a | fgrep "inet " | grep -ve " tun" -e " lo" || echo localhost`

Comment: and use `grep -q` to inhibit the output if it's not going to be used anyway

Answer (score 1):

The package `moreutils` provides `ifne` tool. Normally `ifne` runs the given command if and only if the standard input is *not* empty. It has, however, a *reverse operation* mode:

> ```
> -n
> ```
>
> Reverse operation. Run the command if the standard input is empty.
>
> Note that if the standard input is not empty, it is passed through `ifne` in this case.

Use it like this:

```
ip a | fgrep "inet " | grep -ve " tun" -e " lo" | ifne -n echo "localhost"
```

This is what makes it different from other answers:

- the solution does not rely on exit status of any command;
- `ifne` does not consume the stream if it's not empty (it's unclear if this is what you want).

---

An alternative for text is `awk '{print} END {if (NR==0) print "localhost"}'`. For data that is not text (in terms of POSIX: NUL character(s), exceeded {LINE_MAX}, incomplete line) `awk` may not work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple condition like this ?

```
[[ -z $(ip a | fgrep "inet " | grep -ve " tun" -e " lo") ]] && echo localhost
```